# Dynamically change height of item based on length of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working with cordova and jquery mobile, iam working on an app where I can send notifications. In the notification panel I show all recieved notifications.

So the html markup of that notification is like this:

```
 for(var count = 0; count < info.data.length; count++){
    var shortmessage = info.data[count][3];
    var category = info.data[count][4];
    var typeOf = info.data[count][5];
    var style = '';

    if(typeOf === "warning"){
        imgPath = 'img/icons/alarm.png';
    } else {
        imgPath = 'img/icons/alert.png';
    }

    console.log(shortmessage, shortmessage.length);

     // if long message, set the style
    if ( shortmessage.length > 40 ){
        style = 'min-height: 70px';
    }else if ( shortmessage.length > 65 ){
        style = 'min-height: 80px !important';
    }else if ( shortmessage.length > 75 ){
        style = 'min-height: 100px !important';
    }

if (category === 'vertrek'){
               departureHtml = `
                ${departureHtml}
                <div class='notification-item' style='${style}'>
                    <div class='ui-grid-a notification-grid'>
                        <div class='ui-block-a'>
                            <img class='notification-image' src='${imgPath}'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='ui-block-b'>
                            <span class='notification-text'>${shortmessage}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;

            $('.departure-notification-append').empty().prepend(departureHtml);
        }

        if (category === 'inchecken'){
            incheckHtml = `
                ${incheckHtml}
                <div class='notification-item' style='${style}'>
                    <div class='ui-grid-a notification-grid'>
                        <div class='ui-block-a'>
                            <img class='notification-image' src='${imgPath}'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='ui-block-b'>
                            <span class='notification-text'>${shortmessage}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;

            $('.check-in-notification-append').empty().prepend(incheckHtml);
        }
```

These are two of the 5 categories, but it seems to see that it is greater than 40 than it assigns the `height of 70px` to all of the `notification-items.` But than it doesn't change the height of messages greater than 65 and 75.

So my question is how can I dynamically set the height of a  `notification-item`based on the text inside `notification-text`

Comment: why you are not using height : auto style?

Comment: You indicated you have a jfiddle you're trying to recreate? Could we get a link?

Comment: very weird the only difference is that I now set it as hard html and in my app it is dynamically added by a notification http://jsfiddle.net/sylvanR/hp9cq3k8/2/
.

when I set my height to auto there is no background at all

Answer (score 0):

Setting `height: auto` will allow items to dynamically resize to occupy whatever height is necessary to render their contents.

I would use padding to achieve additional height manipulations rather than mucking with the height property.

Comment: for some reason that is not working because it has to be an min-height and when I set min-height. All of the items will appear the min-height. I wanted to recreate an fiddle with just only the notification-item but than it will change its height..

Comment: That is correct. A minimum height is a minimum. So the items will display at that height. It sounds like an issue of scope. Give your element a unique classname and assign the `height: auto` property to that.